# can web developer do Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: javascript, php, titanium, appcelerator

I am a Web developer.I having knowledge of Core-PHP,mysql,Javascript,jquery.I have Six months exp in PHP development.Now I am getting an offer of Appcelerator Titanium Developer.What is Appcelerator Titanium.The company offered me that they will provide training of Appcelerator Titanium .I am looking for job change.Please suggest me what i have to do.company requirment is Javascript,which i know.Now i am too confused.i have no awareness about Appcelerator Titanium .someone told me that is will the future of mobile app development.Now i am puzzled.please suggest me what i have to do ?

Comment: This isn't really the right site for this kind of question. You can easily read up on what Titanium is by visiting their website and seeing it for yourself as well as looking through questions tagged titanium on this site to see what kinds of problems you might get in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a mobile phone abstratation.

With it you can develop for android phones and apple phones using javascript. 
You can see a quick tour for developers [here](http://www.appcelerator.com/developers/).

Its going to be a stretch but if you put the hours in and have the time and willing to read a book or 2 I just say go for it.

Comment: what is the future scope of titanimum.I am a PHP developer.now i am totally confused.

Comment: Well who knows what the future will bring. But there will be consolidation in tooling for mobile apps. There are no guarantiees, my money is on Xamarin (based on mono which is open source c#). But you sound young, Don't worry, there will be many technologies that will come, shine and then fade to obscurity. And those who master many technologies/languages will have an advantage over those who agonize and only touch the TRUE language or this is the ONLY way to do development. Grab a good oppertuinity, ride with it and enjoy it. Don't worry about if it's a good technology or not.